# String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan. Error in C# inserting time to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I'm using this code to insert time into a SQL database:

```
TimeSpan.Parse(string.Format(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), "hh:Mi"))
```

I tried to change the syntax of time "hh:mm:ss" and "hh:mm tt"

Comment: How about you explain EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve, instead of making us work it out from your code? What EXACTLY do you want to save? "hh:Mi" makes no real sense because lower-case "h" is for 12-hour time, upper-case "M" is for month and "i" means nothing useful. Maybe "HH:mm" is what you want, but that's a guess because your other two attempts don't match that.

Comment: I need to store time from c# to sql database as 18:33  or 07:22 PM

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you need to ALWAYS read the documentation. If you had done that then you'd know that your first format string makes no sense and the valid format strings for `TimeSpans` are different to `DateTimes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using any strings at all. If you want a `TimeSpan` containing the current time then create that:

```cs
var currentTime = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hours, DateTime.Now.Minutes, 0);
```

If you're saving to a database column that is an actual time data type, that's what you want.

As pointed out in the comments, there's a non-zero probability of the the hour ticking over between the two uses of `DateTime.Now` in the code above. To avoid that, you can introduce an additional variable or even reuse the same one:

```cs
var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

currentTime = new TimeSpan(currentTime.Hours, currentTime.Minutes, 0);
```

I almost mistakenly wrote VB to start with and was going to use a `With` block to create an implicit variable, but C# has no equivalent.

Comment: There is a slight change that the minutes will roll over from 59 to 0 just after the call to Hour. Better: `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`

Comment: @KlausGütter, using `TimeOfDay` would give seconds and fractional seconds as well, which the OP appears not to want, which is why I didn't use it directly. If the database data type would truncate that then it's a moot point. If not, to avoid the issue you rightly point out, it would be best to use a variable get a single time and then use that variable in code like above. I have updated the answer to address this.